# Is there any performance difference between use natural join and set operator intersect?

Tags: sql, oracle, set-intersection, natural-join

I'm practicing on the standard HR Oracle database and I have doubts about the use of the set operator INTERSECT. I have these situations:

```
SELECT       employee_id, job_id, department_id
FROM         employees
NATURAL JOIN job_history;
```

[image: NATURAL JOIN Results]

```
SELECT employee_id, job_id, department_id
FROM   employees 
INTERSECT
SELECT employee_id, job_id, department_id 
FROM   job_history;
```

[image: INTERSECT Results]

Both statements have the same set of results. Is there any performance difference??? Thanks.

Comment: You can check that by running against your data.

Comment: Use SQL*Developer's EXPLAIN PLAN functionality (F10?) and it will tell you.

Comment: My god, I didn't see it!!! Thanks

Comment: You should always make it a habit to alias every field in a query. I can't tell which table those are coming from. Natural join is also a very bad tool to use, use an inner JoIn and specify the join fields. YOu need to do some reading on SQL antipatterns.

Comment: In general, `natural join`s and the `intersect` operator can result in different results if the tables in question don't have the same column names and datatypes. Regardless, I'll echo @HGLEM's advice above that `natural join`s are a bad idea. Sure, they seem easier to use, but if you look back at SQL that uses it months later--and perhaps not remembering which tables contain which columns--you'll likely come across maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 2):

`Natural join` is a very different operation from `intersect`.

It seems in both queries you are only selecting the columns that exist, with the same name, in both tables. (Otherwise comparing `natural join` with `intersect` wouldn't make sense to begin with.) That is something you should make clear in your problem statement.

Then: if for the same `employee/job/department` there are several rows in the `job_history` table, then the same number of rows will exist in the natural join (assuming `employee_id` is PK in `employees`). On the other hand, `intersect` removes duplicates. So, even in the way you set this up, the two operations are not the same - unless you are willing to `SELECT DISTINCT` before (or after) the join, which would add that much more overhead.

If you need an `intersect`, then use the `intersect` operator, that's what it is for. Whenever you think you found another way to get the same result, most often it will be because you overlooked something (like the treatment of duplicates in this case).

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's Natural Join excludes identical matches from two tables if any column value is NULL.

Given Tables:

```
    +--------------------------------------+
    |           employees                  |
    +--------------------------------------+
    | employee_id | job_id | department_id |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   1         |  NULL  |  10           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   2         |  EMPTY |  20           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   3         |  "id3" |  30           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
```

And:

```
    +--------------------------------------+
    |           job_history                |
    +--------------------------------------+
    | employee_id | job_id | department_id |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   1         |  NULL  |  10           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   2         |  EMPTY |  20           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
    |   3         |  "id3" |  30           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+   
    |   4         |  "id4" |  40           |
    +-------------+--------+---------------+
```

```
select * from employees natural join job_history
```

Result:

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+
|   2         |  EMPTY |  20           |
+-------------+--------+---------------+
|   3         |  "id3" |  30           |
+-------------+--------+---------------+
```

```
select * from employees intersect select * from job_history
```

Result:

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+
|   1         |  NULL  |  10           |
+-------------+--------+---------------+
|   2         |  EMPTY |  20           |
+-------------+--------+---------------+
|   3         |  "id3" |  30           |
+-------------+--------+---------------+
```